# Cork on _top_ of hardwood floors?

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, hardwood, cork

I have hardwood floors in a rental unit and I'd like to turn a portion of one room into a 'workspace'. But I'd also like to protect the floors from minor spills, tools falling, etc.

I know that some latex-based rug mats can eventually stain hardwood floors, but what about cork? I also know cork is commonly used *under* the floors, however in this situation I'm considering laying cork out *on top* of the floors ... has anyone done this in the past? Yea/Nay?

Answer (score 1):

There is made an interlocking 1/2" deep foam rubber pad made to be use on basement and shop floors for just this purpose.  These pads come in colors for play rooms of in black for work space.  they fit together fairly tightly. They come in 2x2' squares and I believe 2x3' rectangles.  Good Luck